# Cannot install Core, unlikely download issues reported

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to install Janestreet's Core for OCaml using opam on Mac OsX to get started with the "Real world OCaml" book.

I get the following error:

```
===== ERROR while installing herelib.109.35.02 =====
Could not get the source for herelib.109.35.02:
# opam-version    1.1.1
# os              darwin
Cannot download https://opam.ocaml.org/archives/herelib.109.35.02+opam.tar.gz,
please check your connection settings.
```

All other libraries after `herelib` fail as well.

I don't have connection problems, though, as the libraries up to `herelib` do download (last successful is `type_conv` as far as I can tell). Also, pasting the reported URL in Chrome starts a file download immediately, so it doesn't seem to be a server problem at the source.

Homebrew reports my Opam and Ocaml as up to date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version numbers for both `herelib` and `opam` looks quite outdated. The following may help:

1. Update your repository with `opam update`
2. Try to use more recent `opam`, it is available under macports and brew.